# C++ Forward Declaration Error using Struct in Class as well as Constructor and Header

Tags: c++, struct

I have posted this already one day ago but I did not know how to add a second question to my first question.
I get a forward declaration error. You told me that it should be no problem if I define my class in KdTree.h and my functions, structs, etc in KdTree.cpp. However it does not work so here I post my whole code:

This is my header:

```
#Includes <iostream>
#Includes others
using namespace TooN;
#ifndef KDTREE_H_
#define KDTREE_H_
class KdTree {
       public:
       KdTree(std::vector<TooN::Vector<3,GLfloat> > & ,size_t);
       struct node;
       struct temptask;
       struct temphold;
       struct ...;
       double function(...);
       ...;
       std::vector<node> nodes;
       std::vector < int > searchInRadius(const TooN::Vector<3, GLfloat> &,float , const std::vector<TooN::Vector<3,GLfloat> > & );
};
#endif
```

So and this is my KdTree.cpp:

```
#include "KdTree.h"
KdTree::KdTree(std::vector<TooN::Vector<3,GLfloat> > & points, size_t pointssize){

const size_t stacksize = 200;
nodes.push_back(node());
temphold tasksarray[stacksize] = {0,pointssize-1,0,0}; 
int taskindex = 0;
...A lot more stuff

    if (!is_leaf(n)){
    do something;
    }

}
```

And then my functions in KdTree.cpp

```
struct KdTree::node{

    std::size_t a, b, c;
    node() : a(-1), b(-1), c(-1) {}
    bool is_leaf(const node &n){
    return blablabla;
    }

};
```

And here my first 3 Compiler messages:( :

```
jni/Visual/KdTree.cpp: In constructor 'KdTree::KdTree(const std::vector<TooN::Vector<3, float> >&, size_t)':
jni/Visual/KdTree.cpp:32:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct KdTree::node'
  nodes.push_back(node());
                       ^
In file included from jni/Visual/KdTree.cpp:8:0:
jni/Visual/KdTree.h:29:9: error: forward declaration of 'struct KdTree::node'
  struct node;
         ^
jni/Visual/KdTree.cpp:33:54: error: elements of array 'KdTree::temphold tasksarray [200]' have incomplete type
  temphold tasksarray[stacksize] = {0,pointssize-1,0,0}; //starting at firstpoint = 0 index, lastpoint = lastindex, nodenumber = 0 index, dim = x-dimension (i.e. 0)
```

And a lot more of these kind of messages.

Answer (score 0):

The struct definitions must still occur before their first use in the .cpp file.

```
#include "KdTree.h"

struct KdTree::node{
    std::size_t a, b, c;
    node() : a(-1), b(-1), c(-1) {}
    bool is_leaf(const node &n){
    return blablabla;
    }
};


KdTree::KdTree(std::vector<TooN::Vector<3,GLfloat> > & points, size_t pointssize){
  ...A lot more stuff
}
```

Comment: I added "friend" in front of bool is_leaf and now everything works fine. Thanks a lot to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Put the implementation of `node` at the beginning of `KdTree.cpp`, or at least before its first use:

```
#include "KdTree.h"

struct KdTree::node {
   // ...
};

KdTree::KdTree() {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks to you guys!!! My errors went from 50 to 1. The final error is that: 'KdTree::KdTree(std::vector<TooN::Vector<3, float>>&, size_t)':jni/Visual/KdTree.cpp:109:22: error: 'is_leaf' was not declared in this scope if (!is_leaf(n)){}.

So basically it does not know my function in my struct (which I have put before my constructor now).

Any ideas? Thanks.